# Parent for a single (single.php)

Tags: pages, single

Is it posible to get the parent ID of an single page.... I mean not a Page I mean an is_single()... page.

I have a page witch contains some custom posts and when I click on one of these i came to the single page of these entree. I would like to get the permalink of the parent page, the page i come from.

Answer (score 0):

For a hierarchical post type, you can use `$post->post_parent` and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink), perhaps like so:

```
<?php
global $post;
$parent_permalink = get_permalink( $post->post_parent );
?>
<a href="<?php echo $parent_permalink; ?>">Parent Post</a>
```

Comment: thats clear, but im on a single.php page i get no parent in the body class etc.
      <body class="single single-news postid-1098 single-format-standard">

Comment: Modifying `body_class` sounds like a separate question/issue.

Comment: Parent information classes are added to the body class in `get_body_class()` under the test for is_page(). The code under the `is_single()` test does not add those classes. If you want them on your CPT single.php page body class, you will have to add them yourself.

Comment: If this answer does not adequately answer your underlying question, please **edit your question**, to clarify more precisely what you're trying to accomplish. Then, I can edit the answer accordingly.